# AdSense Ads not showing sometimes

Tags: javascript, ads, adsense

It seems ads somehow conflict which each other. Normally I have 2 ads displaying at the same time with no issues, but on search pages I have 3 ads and most of the time only the first works.

http://chusmix.com/?s=Buenos+Aires

I simply copy pasted the code in the three places:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-7097762525948790";
/* Chusmix 728x90 Grafico */
google_ad_slot = "9872841053";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->

</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

The other ads code is basically the same save with different width, height and name. Did I do something wrong? Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one of those ads you're inserting some HTML in between the JavaScript, don't do that. Always wrap HTML around the complete ad code.

Also, realize that not all ad units may be filled if there aren't enough ads. That's why you need to use the alternate ad URL feature of AdSense to display something else in its place in those cases.